# How is the hash object and cache array used in this snippet?

Tags: javascript

I understand preloading the url but I do not understand the purpose of cache and hash in this snippet. I know the answer is probably simple and I’m overlooking it but I just want some direction.

```
const hash = {};
const cache = [];

const add = (url) => {
    if (!hash[url]) {
        hash[url] = new Image();

        hash[url].src = url;

        cache.push(hash[url]);
    }
    return hash[url];
};
```

Comment: Where else is `cache` used? (Indeed it doesn't really serve any purpose but to leak memory in the snippet you posted). Where did you find this code?

Answer (score 0):

In this example, `cache` is actually useless. You only write to it and never read from it.

`hash` is being used as the actual cache here. If an image with the same URL already exists, it will be returned from the `hash` object, and not created again.

Comment: When I first read it I had no idea what the cache was doing because it made sense that hash returned the url already for the preloaded image but I dIdnt understand the purpose of the cache